# Why in JavaScript class A instanceof Function, but typeof class A is not an object?

Tags: javascript, types

When we say "instance of", we assume that we are dealing with an object. Why JavaScript's operator `instanceof` returns `true` when we ask `(class A { }) instanceof Function`, but `typeof (class A { }) == "function"`? Why not `object`?

Comment: You are dealing with an object. Functions are objects in Javascript.

Comment: Why is it surprising that an instance of a function has a type of "function"? Seems to me like it would be an important type distinction.

Comment: @squint, but ... but class is not an object =). Now obviously this does not apply to JavaScript...

Comment: @ktretyak: Classes are functions and functions are objects. It's like a type hierarchy. The top you have Object. Array and Function are more concrete variants of Object. Functions can further be distinguished between callable and constructable functions.

Comment: @ktretyak The syntax is extremely misleading in what `class` actually does. This is one reason why I don't like using it. JavaScript never has, and still does not have class-based object-oriented programming.

Comment: The syntax is really only misleading if you assume the semantics of other languages, which is never a wise move.

Comment: @4castle: Maybe you feel less negative about classes if you think about syntax being a way of expressing *intent*. And hopefully a language evolves to make it easier to express intent. You could also consider array literals to be misleading, since they actually create objects. But it expresses the intent better than using an object literal (plus other goodies, like `length`). Or think about IIFEs vs `let`. It might just be a matter of time to get used to new things and properly place them in your mental model of the language (that was the case for me at least).

Comment: @FelixKling My primary issue with `class` is that it makes me think too much in terms of classifications of objects and strictly typed languages. I find that the `prototype` syntax communicates my intent more efficiently, and allows for more useful capabilities, such as private functions. I use Java every day, so using a syntax this similar just actively hampers my ability to model objects effectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why JavaScript's operator `instanceof` returns true when we ask `(class A { }) instanceof Function`

`class`es are just syntactic sugar for constructor functions. I.e. the evaluation of `class A {}` produces a function.

The following two examples are (more or less) equivalent, i.e. they produce the same result/value:

```
// class
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 42;
  }

  bar() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}

// constructor function
function A() {
  this.foo = 42;
}

A.prototype.bar = function() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}
```

Everything that is not a primitive value (string, number, boolean, null, undefined, symbol) is an object in JavaScript. Functions are objects too, with special internal properties that makes them *callable* (and/or *constructable*).

---

> Why not object?

`typeof` returns the string `"function"` for function values because that's how it is defined in the specification.