# Clarification on typeof class

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

So I am writing few test cases. I have one class as follows.

```
export default class DateProcessor {
    requestHandler = (req, res) => {
        //code
    }
}
```

Now I am writing one unit test to see if the typeof DateProcessor is class

```
import {default as processor} from './getDatesProcessor';

describe('Date Processor', () => {
    it('should be a class', () => {
        expect(typeof processor).toBe('class');
    })
});
```

But the test case is failing because I am getting the type as a function and not a class.
I want to know if this is the expected behavior or I am not doing something right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why in JavaScript class A instanceof Function, but typeof class A is not an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100659/why-in-javascript-class-a-instanceof-function-but-typeof-class-a-is-not-an-obje)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: **yes, it is expected behavior**

Explanation:
In JavaScript, there's no such thing as class. The `class` keyword is just a syntax which makes it easier to create prototypes according to best practices. In fact, all those *classes* are actually *functions*. You can check it using `typeof` keyword which will return `function` when applied to a *class*. Also, this is also possible in JavaScript:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function () {
  return this.name;
}

class Student extends Person {

  constructor(name, studies) {
    super(name);
  
    this.studies = studies;
  }
  
  getStudies() {
    return this.studies;
  }
}

const s = new Student('John', 'Maths');
console.log(s.getName(), s.getStudies());
```

More on classes in JS, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Sebastian. I got my question clarified. I was under the impression that I should get a type of class. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before JavaScript had classes, you had to emulate classes using functions (with some special syntax `new`/`this`).

```js
export default class DateProcessor {
    requestHandler = (req, res) => {
        //code
    }
}
```

Your code is (roughly) equivalent to:

```js
export default function DateProcessor() {
  this.requestHandler = (req, res) => {

  }
}
```

Even though there's a dedicated `class` keyword these days, they're still implemented as functions that must be called with the `new` keyword, therefore `typeof` still regards them as functions.

It's worth reading the [MDN docs for typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to see that there aren't many possible return values.