# Can ES6 class inheritance be translated into equivalent ES5 code?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, prototype

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42100695/200783) shows how a simple ES6 class:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 42;
  }

  bar() {
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
}
```

is equivalent the following ES5 code:

```
function A() {
  this.foo = 42;
}

A.prototype.bar = function() {
  console.log(this.foo);
}
```

Is is similarly possible to translate ES6 class inheritance to ES5 code? What would be the ES5 equivalent to following derived class?

```
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.foo2 = 12;
  }

  bar() {
    console.log(this.foo + this.foo2);
  }

  baz() {
    console.log(this.foo - this.foo2);
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://babeljs.io/ and play in https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: and the code you asked about ... https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=usage&spec=true&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBC0FMAeAXBA7AJjAgtA3gFDTTAD26EKATgK7ApnUAUAlAcSdBLQA4ItWAbk4kUACwCWEAHQAzMmQBM0ALzQAjEpEkAvoU4AjMII5dSFCGRAIZIMgHNmE6fMXQA1NBeyFy4Zz6RmAAXmxmXOSU1rb2Tj5uZNAAtN5SvopKAXqEukA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=true&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.7.7&externalPlugins=

Comment: Here's a good guide about [prototypal inheritance from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance)

Comment: Yes. The class notation is just syntactic sugar. You can actually do more with ES5 code. For example the class notation don't support static data on the class, and with ES5 syntax you can use named functions (so the function can call itself). You can mix both, if you need it.

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent in the sense of how it was done before (ignoring exact behaviours like property enumerability and extending actual ES6 classes from ES5-compatible code) was to:

- set the child prototype to a new object inheriting the parent prototype
- call the parent constructor from the child constructor

```
function B() {
  A.call(this);
  this.foo2 = 12;
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

B.prototype.bar = function () {
  console.log(this.foo + this.foo2);
};

B.prototype.baz = function () {
  console.log(this.foo - this.foo2);
};
```

It was also possible to inherit properties of the constructor (“static”) using the de facto facility for modification of existing prototypes: `B.__proto__ = A`

Comment: It would be better to use `Object.defineProperty` to set the constructor property as non-enumerable to prevent it from being iterated within a `for in...` loop, but if it's not a concern then it should be fine.

Comment: @ryeballar If there is more than one property, [Object.defineProperties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) is also available.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the Babel-generated code is more-or-less equivalent to this, including the `Object.setPrototypeOf(B, A)` step.